# The sleep state of a PC via VbScript

Tags: vbscript

The sleep state of a PC, from power profile "Put the computer to sleep: Never" can be checked from windows UI.

Is there any way the same can be checked from vbscript/javascript.

The idea is to check if the pc in which a web application (localhost) is running has set the "Put computer to sleep:10/15/.. mins"

Just check and flag.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: from cmd;  prompt:\> powercfg -q  gives a long result in Win7, XP is shorter.  from that list, a small portion,  Subgroup GUID: 238c9fa8-0aad-41ed-83f4-97be242c8f20  (Sleep)  
Power Setting GUID: 29f6c1db-86da-48c5-9fdb-f2b67b1f44da  (Sleep after)  
Minimum Possible Setting: 0x00000000  
Maximum Possible Setting: 0xffffffff  
Possible Settings increment: 0x00000001  
Possible Settings units: Seconds  
Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000000  
Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000000  

0x00000000=Never (PS: sorry for the bad formatting,i thought double space = line break but i guess not)

Comment: Please update your question with the output. It's unreadable when you post it as a comment.